# TSQL: How extract only a fixed length of numbers from string

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a huge list of customer data. I want to get only the 5 digits post code from `Address1` column.

I have the messy code below:

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT LEFT(SUBSTRING(Address1, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', Address1), 8000),
       PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', SUBSTRING(Address1, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', Address1), 8000) + 'X') -1)) 
FROM CustomerList where LEN(LEFT(SUBSTRING(Address1, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', Address1), 8000),
       PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', SUBSTRING(Address1, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', Address1), 8000) + 'X') -1)) = 5 -- Get only records that has exactly 5 value
```

For above code, the following data will work:

"Str. Jt. Jones 40030" - Can get "40030"

But following data does not work:

"22 Str. Mel 50630" - Can only get "22" street number, not post code.

"65-31 Kampar 47000 Bau" - Can only get 65

"Lot 199 Guasa 30990 Omar" - Can only get 199

So my code can get those records that have post code only. If the `Address1` contain other numbers, it doesn't work.

Please help.

EDIT:

Apparently my current code is begin reading the digits from `LEFT', is there any way I can modify the current code to start reading from RIGHT instead?

Comment: Is the Postcode in your data always at the end / the last part of the address?

Comment: If you have a huge list of data the post code should be a *separate* field. Imagine parsing 1M rows every time you want to serch for *one* post code.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The data is provided by client, so I need to filter and separate to another column now.

Comment: @Tyron78 as far as I see, yes most of the post code the near the last part

Comment: @KooSengSeng this is called cleansing. It's a lot easier to do this using SSIS or a program. Instead of writing all this code, you just extract the last five characters while *loading* the data into your own database

Comment: can you post different examples?  For the two record you post you can simply use RIGHT (, 5)

Comment: @KooSengSeng with SSIS or an application you could use a regex or string manipulation to extract the field you want and store it as an extra column in a table that holds cleaned up data.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos for this process I don't have any plan on using any application, that might take more time since I already have the data inside database, I just need to look for a way to extract only the 5 digits and insert to another column

Comment: @KooSengSeng on the contrary, just trying to make T-SQL perform a regex is going to take a lot more time. Besides, if you *really* have a lot of data, a single query will lock the entire table, eat up server memory and maintain *all* locks until the transformation is finished. It's *far* faster to pull the data, transform  it and write it out.

Comment: @KooSengSeng what you have is a staging table. Obviously it's *not* suitable for your work, which means you need to transform it into a form that *is* suitable. And you can't do it on the source data. It's not just that a single mistake will require reloading everything. The schema is almost certainly not suitable for your reporting needs. That's why ETL tools and separate reporting schemas and/or star schemas are used.

Comment: @KooSengSeng for example, why perform slow aggregations on the source data when you can load the data into a columnstore table and have it take 5 times less space but give you 100 times faster aggregate queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about simply stripping the last part of your addresses? Such as:

```
DECLARE @Address1 NVARCHAR(100) = 'Lot 199 Guasa 30990 Omar';
SELECT 
  (SELECT REVERSE(LEFT(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@Address1), PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', REVERSE(@Address1)), 8000),
     PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@Address1), PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', REVERSE(@Address1)), 8000) + 'X') -1))) AS PostCode
```

Comment: Sorry I just added another 2 sample data, which using `RIGHT` doesn't work because the post code is not exactly at the last part

Comment: I modified the query: using your Regexp on the reversed string and reversing the result once more...

Comment: wow nice. Learn something new about `REVERSE`. Thanks a lot, really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

With examples you post you can try to  use something like this:

```
WITH X AS (SELECT '65-31 Kampar 47000 Bau' AS A UNION ALL SELECT 'Str. Jt. Jones 40030' UNION ALL SELECT 'Lot 199 Guasa 30990 Omar'  )

SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTRING( REVERSE(A), patindex('%[0-9]%', REVERSE(A)) ,5) ) FROM X
```

Output:

```
47000
40030
30990
```